# How to listen to view visibility status on screen in a scrollview in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, view, android-viewpager

I have bunch of views onscreen CardView, ViewPager etc inside a scrollview.I want to listen to visibility changes of items on screen like if a particular view goes out of the visible screen like when scrolled i want to listen to that change.How do i achieve this ?

Comment: not sure if you can do this with just a scrollview, but if you put each of these items into a recyclerview and use custom viewholders, you can then see what type of view is binding and then do whatever you need to

Comment: Can't you get the index of the items in the view and calculate the position of these items? So you have the height of the items in the scroll view, and height of the scroll view container and the index of the middle item in the scroll view. You can know if the item is out of visible scroll view range once its index is passed, or yet to come.

Comment: that actually worked @BoraSumer

Comment: Awesome, I am glad it worked. @user5444140